# Retrieve Backbone Collection from Model and keep it as a Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, model

I'm currently fooling around with backbone.js and came across some wierd behaviour trying to create some relationships between models and collections.

So here is my Model/Collection

```
Element = Backbone.Model.extend({
  name: 'element'
});

Elements = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  name: 'elements',
  model: Element
});

Application = Backbone.Model.extend({
  name: 'app',
  initialize: function() {
    this.elements = new Elements(this.get('elements'));
  } 
});
```

When I retrieve the elements via `application.get('elements')` I get a '`false`' asking if this new Object is an instanceof `Backbone.Collection`.

```
var gotElements = application.get('elements');
var isCollection = gotElements instanceof Backbone.Collection;
```

So am I doing something wrong, or do I have to create a new Collection-Instance and fill it up with the Collection I receive from the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your initialize function doing this.elements sets a property called 'elements' directly on your model (so model.elements will be your Backbone collection). The problem is when you try to retrieve this.elements by calling application.get('elements'), you will see it returns undefined (which is why it is not an instance of a Backbone collection).

In order for a model attribute to be retrievable using model.get it needs be set with model.set(attribute). If you examine the model in the console you will see the difference. model.set(myData) adds your data to the model's attributes hash. model.myData = myData adds a 'myData' property directly to the model.

To get this to work you can do the following:

```
Element = Backbone.Model.extend({
  name: 'element'
});

Elements = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  name: 'elements',
  model: Element
});

Application = Backbone.Model.extend({
  name: 'app',
  elements: null
});

var application = new Application({
  elements: new Elements()
});

var myElements = application.get('elements');
```

myElements should now be an empty Backbone Collection

Comment: Thanks mcbex! I'm less confused as before. According to my actual question your answer is perfectly fine. I'm trying to reuse the models and exact state of my application on the server and client but it seems to keep both in sync is more of a hazzle than it could give a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your collection into another model, you should put it in the according view:

```
var ListView = new Backbone.View.extend({
     initialize:function(){
         this.Elements= new Elements();
         // more stuff to go
     },
     render:function(){
          _.forEach(this.Elements, function(){
         //Do rendering stuff of indivdual elements and get HTML
         });
         //put HTML in the DOM
     }
});
```

There is no need of a model containing a collection containing several models.

Edit: And instead of putting your app into a Model, you should put it into a view.

Comment: But then, where's the separation between data (models) and ui (views)? I'd like to have a single "Object" representing the whole application-State on a client, therefore putting it into a view doesn't make sense as I can't simply replace the view with let's say more detailed view showing more attributes of the model.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you want decoupled reuse of your collection, coupling it to a view makes no sense. My approach was for the straightforward case, that you have only one view per collection.

Comment: Many Thanks Lilith2k3, makes sense now ;)